# Update / migration - Admob play service Ads 19.8.0

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, google-play-services

I have updated to the new version of com.google.android.gms: **play-services-ads: 19.8.0** from Admob, but I can't get it to work.

I have read to migrate from version 19.7.0 of google play service ads.
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/migration
I have tried my code in different ways and it does not work.

One of the errors is: 'com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd' is deprecated  → I have solved it with an import com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAd;

After importing .... InterstitialAd I got different errors such as:

Cannot resolve method 'setAdUnitId' in 'InterstitialAd'

Cannot resolve method 'loadAd' in 'InterstitialAd'

Cannot resolve method 'isLoaded' in 'InterstitialAd'

Example of my code: (works in older versions)

```
package com.ejemplo.mejorar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAd;
//import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    //Variables code admob Ads & interstitial//
    private InterstitialAd interstitialAd = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(com.ejemplo.mejorar.R.layout.activity_main);


        //Interstitial -------------

        AdRequest adrequest_interstitial = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitialAd.setAdUnitId("CODEADMOB");
        interstitialAd.loadAd(adrequest_interstitial);

    }

    //Inicio paginas----------------------------------------------------
    public void page1(View view)
    {


        Intent i = new Intent (this, PaginaConf.class);
        startActivity(i);

        int randomAd = (int)(Math.random()*10);
        if(interstitialAd!=null && randomAd<=1)
        {
            if(interstitialAd.isLoaded()){ interstitialAd.show(); }

        }


    }


    //---------------------------------------------

    public void close(View view)
    {
        finish();
    }



}
```

Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

I'm a little lost hehe

thank you and sorry for my english

Answer (score 2):

The new Interstitial APIs no longer support those methods. To use `com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAd`, see the updated integration guides for Interstitial: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial-fullscreen.